# Using projection while retrieving from Azure Search Index

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-search

Here I am retrieving the list of products from azure search index using a query. In this, I obtain a list of images for a particular product.

```
 public class ProductImage
{

        public string Id { get; set; }

        [IsSearchable]
        public string ActualSizeUrl { get; set; }

        public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
}
```

For example I am currently getting the following actual size url: `5de4ff7246bfe0002579328b/5da957c9e158618c1bbce366.jpg`

Using this code

```
var results = _indexClient.Documents.Search<Product>(searchText, parameters);

IEnumerable<SearchResult<Product>> itemList = results.Results.AsEnumerable();

IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> items = itemList.Select(x => new SearchResultItem
            {
                Data = x.Document,
                Confidence = x.Score,
                Type = Enum.GetName(typeof(SearchType), SearchType.Product),
            });
```

How to achieve the actual size URL like this : `http://localhost:10000/devstoreaccount1/5de4ff7246bfe0002579328b/5da957c9e158618c1bbce366.jpg` while I retrieve from search Index

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to just compose the full URL in your application code.

In .Net, you can use a calculated property in the ProductImage class that creates the URL in the get using the value from the index and some fixed root URL.

You can use the [JsonIgnore] attribute so it isn’t mapped to a field in your index.

thanks,
Abby